# Custom event parameters not being sent

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js

First off: I'm very new to Google Analytics!

I'm trying to use GA to track a custom event with some custom parameters, but I'm not doing very well. I've set up `gtag.js` according to [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/) and it is working if I only set the following parameters:

```
function trackOutboundLink(url) {
        gtag('event', 'click', {
            'event_category': 'outbound',
            'event_label': url,
            'transport_type': 'beacon',
            'event_callback': function() {
                document.location = url;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

But I would like to set some additional parameters and according to [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events) it should be possible:
"You can add custom data, in the form of additional parameters, to any event (recommended or custom)"

I'm setting up GA using this:

```
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MY_GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'MY_GA_TRACKING_ID');

</script>
```

And I'm calling `gtag()` the following way:

```
function trackOutboundLinkWithCustomParameters(label, version, url) {
        gtag('event', 'click', {
            'event_category': 'outbound',
            'event_label': label,
            'transport_type': 'beacon',
            'mobile_app_version': version,
            'download_url': url,
            'event_callback': function() {
                document.location = url;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

If I break at `dataLayer.push(arguments);` and prints `arguments` I get the following (which is what I want to track):
[image: arguments]

But after having installed [GA Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) it seems it ignores my extra parameters when sending the tracking data:

[image: GA Debugger output]

Bottom line is: I can't see the additional info I provide about `mobile_app_version` and `download_url` in my GA dashboard.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any custom parameters that you want to see in your standard reports will need to be configured before you send your data in with your event (cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets#send-custom-dimensions), so in your example, you should have something like this:

```
gtag('config', 'MY_GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'custom_map': {
     'dimension1': 'mobile_app_version',
     'dimension2': 'download_url'
  }
})
```

Make sure you have already configured what the custom dimensions are.